# what is the max array size in Javascript and which arrays to use

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted t create a large array in Javascript and wrote the following code but it did not work due to OOM

```
let N = 125000000;
let numbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    numbers[i] = Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
}
```

Then I wrote "let numbers = new Array(N);" instead, which worked for the N (125000000) but did not work with larger N (200000000). Then I used Uint32Array, which worked for even larger N. It worked up to N = 2^31-1.
Is there any limit on size in [], new Array(size), Uint32Array in Javascript? I guess the max size o Uint32Array is 2^31-1. I also want to know why new Array(N) has higher limit than [].
Thank you

Comment: I guess If you're putting numbers into Array literal (`[]`) or Array Object (`new Array(size)`)  they are stored as `signed 64-bit Floating Point number` - `64bits` and If you're putting numbers into `UInt32Array` they are stored as `unsigned 32-bit int numbers` - `32bits`. So, RAM-usage is twice less than in  the first case.

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS follows the [ECMAScript](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) specification, that is implemented via the [V8](https://v8.dev/docs) engine.

The maximum you can fit inside is 4,294,967,295 = 4.29 billion elements.

You ran out of memory because V8 sets a memory limit, you can bypass this limit by invoking Node with 'max-old-space-size' parameter, like so:

> node --max-old-space-size=1024 yourscript.js

Where 1024 is 1GB, 2048  2GB and so goes on.